# Why image not taking the whole width of the browser on MAC?

Tags: html, image, macos, css

I developed a website that contain some images , some of them are main images with about 3000px in width .

I'm using this to make the image fill the whole width and it's working with me during testing but the client said that it's not taking the whole width and sent me screenshots :

```
img{
  display:block;
  max-width:100%
  height:auto;
}
```

Here is the demo link of the website:
http://www.zhtml.aba.ae

How to make it work?

He was browsing it from Chrome Browser on MAC

Comment: you need force the width to be 100%, max-width will only affect it when the image is larger than the browser

Answer (score 1):

You only defined the maximum width, which is 100% of the page. You should try to replace "max-width" for just "width".

```
img{
  display:block;
  width:100%
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the differences by changing your browser: You'll understand the difference.

```
<style>
div.e1 {
    width:400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #73AD21;
}

div.e2 {
    max-width:400px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>

<div class="e1">width: 400px;</div>
<br>

<div class="e2">max-width: 400px;</div>

<p>blablabla</p>
```